# Routes in express JS taken from DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to use routes something like this.

For example :

```js
routes.use((req, res, next) => {
  /**
   * I have an example routes from database and i was passing into variable
   * I'm assign fromDb as 'api/test'
   */
  var a = fromDb;
  next()
})

routes.get(a, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.path)
})
```

I know, `a` variable in next routes do not get a value from DB cause functional scope. So, any idea for solve this method. I just wondering if I can using modular like this

```js
const DBRoutes = require('lib/example.js')

router.get(DBRoutes, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.path)
})
```

Any idea for the best method? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add a route based on content in your database

So you could do the lookup and on success create the route

eg:

```
dbConnection.lookup(...some query)
   .then((pathFromDB) => {
     // where pathfromDb = /api/test
     routes.get(pathFromDB, (req, res, next) => {
       console.log(req.path)
     })
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
routes.use((req, res, next) => {
  /**
   * I have an example routes from database and i was passing into variable
   * I'm assign fromDb as 'api/test'
   */
  res.locals.fromDb = fromDb;
  next()
})

routes.get('/your/route', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.path);
  console.log(res.locals.fromDb);
});
```

This is one way of passing variables through different middlewares in express.

I don't think you can dynamically set up routes for express web server. However, routes are set up once during startup. You can get the routes from database at that time.

```js
const route = await routeFromDatabase();

routes.get(route, (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.path);
  console.log(res.locals.fromDb);
});
```

If you change the database after startup, you will have to restart the node app.

Update 19th Feb 2018: User mentioned the use case as API Gateway. This is worth exploring for such use cases: https://www.express-gateway.io/

Comment: '/your/route'/ is taken from DB, not a static route.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. I realized when you say "Routes are set up once during startup". So, ur right then,, i have to restart the node app when there any changes in database.  As you know, the purpose I'm doing this method for creating an API-Gateway. But anyway, Thanks for explain it